# Build periodically only after another project build is stable

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 Jenkins jobs. Say Job A and Job B.

```
job A --> Runs every 10 minutes (Gets completed in 6-8 minutes)
job B --> Runs every morning at 8 am.
```

Now I need to pick the latest build from job A which runs exactly before 8 am & if that build is **stable**, then only I need to trigger job B.

Please check attached image where job B is getting triggered on every stable build of job A. (Eg. every 10 minutes, instead of once in 24 hours).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Groovy Pipeline to the rescue. Create a Pipeline Job C (and uncheck the "Use Groovy Sandbox" button)

```
def lastBuildResult = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("/JobA").getLastBuild().result.toString()

if (lastBuildResult == "SUCCESS") {
    build '/JobB'
}
```

Put your schedule on Job C.

Alternatively if A is fast and can be re-run you could just re-run A

```
build 'JobA'
build 'JobB'
```

So B doesn't run unless A finishes.